# How many experiments are needed to guarantee that the sum of i.i.d exponential random variables is lower bounded?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am performing the following $n$ i.i.d experiments. Each time $t=1,2,\ldots,n$, I generate a random variable following an exponential distribution $X_t$ with rate $\lambda$. Each time $t$ I do an experiment $X_t$, I calculate the accumaltion $A_t=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_t$. I need to find, for some given positive number $A$:

1. how many experiments (out of $n$) I have to do, in average, in order to have $A_t\geq A$; and
2. the minimum number of experiments I have to do in order to have $A_t\geq A$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The sum of $k$ i.i.d exponential distribution with rate  $\lambda$ is an Erlang distribution $Erlang(k, \lambda)$ or $Gamma(k, \lambda^{-1})$. For your information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions

Comment: How to use your hint to answer my question?

Comment: @zdm I guess you can find some properties of Erlang distribution, i.e. mean, to answer the first question, right? I'm still not clear about the second one, you can still have a very low probability of getting any $X_i$ so small that $A_t$ cannot be greater than $A$

Comment: Using computer evaluation, the answer is $1+A/\lambda$. However, I don't know how to use your hint.